# laravel dompdf Undefined type 'PDF'

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I'm trying to use `dompdf` with Laravel, even though I use the 'use PDF' it's still error.

**Here is my controller**

```
<?php
    
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Pasien;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

use PDF;
    
class PasienController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index() {
        $pasien = DB::table('pasien')->paginate(5);
        return view('pasien/index',  ['pasien' => $pasien]);
    }

    public function createPDF() {
        // retreive all records from db
        $data = Pasien::all();
  
        // share data to view
        view()->share('employee',$data);
        $pdf =  PDF::loadView('pdf_view', $data);
  
        // download PDF file with download method
        return $pdf->download('pdf_file.pdf');
    }
}
```

**The PDF in this line is red**

> $pdf =  PDF::loadView('pdf_view', $data);

**The error display this message**

> Undefined type 'PDF'

**I've put this in the providers**

> Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,

**And this on the aliases**

> 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,

*I've installed the package using composer, and also php artisan vendor publish it.*

Comment: try config:cache command in case if you 've just installed the package

Answer (score 2):

Maulik answer combined with Khalid khan really helped me, and it's actually worked!

**INSTEAD OF**

> use PDF;

**USE THIS**(Even though I heard you can just use, 'use PDF'. But hey it works!)

> use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF;

**And then enter this command**

> php artisan config:cache

### Reset everything, quit your IDE, restart your server, and then try opening your project again.

*You can try clearing the cache first and then modifying your code, or one way another.*

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` should be sufficient you don't have to quit or reset everything or close your server

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8 and above.

**INSTEAD OF**

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
```

**USE**

```
'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf::class,
```

**INSIDE YOUR CONTROLLER:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

$pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf_view', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In mine case it works

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('...');
```

I have added `\` before `PDF` class name with `loadView`.

A `\` before the beginning of a class name represents the [Global Namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php).

Comment: Yes I have imported that in my code so I provide that here but it still works without import :). Solution Updated!

Answer (score 0):

I just added `Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class` in my providers array (inside <path_your_project>**/config/app.php**) and `'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class` in my aliases array (inside the same file) and it worked for me!

Note1: I'm using Laravel 8.0.3

Note2: don't forget of run this:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still stucking, I got same issue, and none of solution helped, for Laravel 9.

This works for me:

```
 use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf;

$pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf.invoice', $data);
return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
```

Instead of using this, Use this with App Container:

```
 $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
return $pdf->stream();
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked in my case. This worked for me, use 'FacadePdf' instead of 'PDF'. I am using Laravel 9.52.7

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade\Pdf as FacadePdf;

$pdf = FacadePdf::loadView('invoice.inv_pdf', [
   'order_id' => $order,
]);
```